# WIX installer with delphi custom actions

Tags: sql-server, delphi, wix

We are writing custom actions using Delphi and wanted to know if there would be any issues with the following or whether one way would be better than the other.

1. Using WMI to determine if SQL server is installed and getting the SQL server instance names.
2. If there is an issue with WMI (exception raised), then use SQLDMO.
3. Using WMI to get the port a website is running on and if IIS is installed.
4. Reading registry values using WMI.

In the case of 1) and 2), should I just use SQLDMO rather WMI.

Thanks.
JD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of searching, the best I have found is http://www.magsys.co.uk/delphi/.

There is a demo project which allows you to change namespaces and test various WQL and instance queries. Hope this helps someone.